# Why won't my Burmy change into trash cloak after battling inside a gym?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm playing Pokémon X and every time I use my burmy inside a gym it doesn't change into a trash cloak pero like I'm battling inside a building. Is it different for generations after gen 4?

Comment: Which gym have you tried?

Comment: I've tried Viola's gym and also Grant's gym.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can get a trash cloak on it is if you battle trainers inside of a city. I prefer Lumios City just because there are trainers outside of buildings and it's a bit easier to find them.

Comment: Do you know around which areas there are trainers to battle in Lumiose?

Comment: @Chip You can battle Essentia in Looker Bureau, or try with the Restaurants.

Comment: Or the various alleyways between the major streets...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to change Burmy's cloak. Still curious to know though why gyms don't count as a building.

Comment: i'm curious, what cloak do you get when you battle in a gym? Assuming you start with trash cloak, as we've established it's not that. Or does it simply invoke no change?